# PHP blank page upon zero results with no error

Tags: php

i have the below php code which retrieves data from my table and display in a nice html format. my problem is when  there is no data. it just display a blank page. how can  i  make it display a page that says no results found without breaking my code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $tmpqid = $_POST["stu_qid"];
    require_once 'dbconfig.php';

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT * 
                FROM as_questions
                WHERE Qid=$tmpqid";



        $q = $conn->query($sql);
        $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    } catch (PDOException $pe) {
        die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
    }
}
?>

  <?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>

    <!-- here goes all the result display -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: run it through a condition like `if ($q->rowCount() !== 0)` { } else { //display the form }`

Comment: @adelowo where would i put it ? inside the while loop? or before?

Comment: @adelowo nvm figured it out :D thanks